# self object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

I would like to define the name of the object 'self' in a class using a string.

This is how I know to do it:

```
   class Test():
        def __init__(name):
            self.var_name=name
```

This is how I would like to do it:

```
   class Test1():
        def __init__(name,var_name):
            self[var_name]=name
```

So that then I can do something like:

```
T1=Test1('aka','dog_name')
T1.dog_name>>> 'aka'

T2=Test1('luna','cat_name')
T2.cat_name >>> 'luna'
```

Is it possible? I tried the *self[var_name]* but doesn't work and I get the error *self object is not subscriptable* so I was wondering if there was another way to do it.

Comment: Are you sure a class is really what you need here? A dictionary might make more sense, if you're just trying to associate arbitrary names with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to check out `setattr()` and while you are at it `getattr()`. Though just the first will get you want I think you are looking for:

```
class Test1():
    def __init__(self, name, var_name):
        setattr(self, var_name, name)

T1=Test1('aka','dog_name')
print(T1.dog_name)
```

Should give you:

```
aka
```